# Which Cuda and cudnn versions are supported by latest tenorflow version 2.2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Which versions of CUDA and CUDNN are required to run the latest TensorFlow 2.2.0 on windows platform?

Answer (score 1):

CUDA 10.1 or 10.2 should both work, your choice I guess which one you would want to use. Then just download the corresponding CUDNN file with the CUDA version you installed.